# Installing npm: segmentation fault after "sudo make install"

Tags: node.js, npm

Im following the instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

and Im getting this:

```
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js install -g -f
make: *** [install] Segmentation fault
```

Any idea?

I have Ubuntu 10.10 and node v0.5.6-pre

Regards

Javi

Comment: Run that exact 'node' command line that's faulting under 'strace' and check the last few system calls. That might point you towards the problem.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're running 0.5.6-pre over the stable branch?

Comment: @einaros, thanks!, 0.5.5 works